# Implement for loop with "python -c" console command mode

Tags: python

I have the below code which I want to run using `python -c` through a shell script:

```
import json,sys
obj=json.loads(open('/temp/209/209formatted_response.json','r').read())
revision=obj['component']['referencingComponents'][0]['revision']

for element in list(revision):
    if 'lastModifier' in element:
        del revision['lastModifier']

print(revision)
```

Using `python -c` , it runs fine without the for loop, but if I include the for loop in it, it throws and error:

Below works fine:

```
python -c "import json,sys; obj=json.loads(open('/temp/209/209formatted_response.json','r').read());revision=obj['component']['referencingComponents'][0]['revision']"
```

The below gives error:

```
$ /opt/app/anaconda3/envs/anaconda3/bin/python -c "import json,sys; obj=json.loads(open('/temp/209/209formatted_response.json','r').read());revision=obj['component']['referencingComponents'][0]['revision'];for element in list(revision):    if 'lastModifier' in element:        del revision['lastModifier']; print(revision)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import json,sys; obj=json.loads(open('/temp/209/209formatted_response.json','r').read());revision=obj['component']['referencingComponents'][0]['revision'];for element in list(revision):    if 'lastModifier' in element:        del revision['lastModifier']; print(revision)
                                                                                                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I even tried using `\n` before each statement of the loop `;` at the end of the line but no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use newlines, but not bluntly adding them:

```
$ python3 -c "exec(\"n = 3\nfor i in range(n):\n  print(i)\")"
0
1
2
```

Add `\n` as you did, but also enclose the code by `"exec(\"...\")"`

Or you can insert real newlines:

```
$ python3 -c "n = 3
> for i in range(n):
>   print(i)"
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with indentation, so instead of using for and if statements you can use **filter** function

```py
revision = list(filter(lambda x: not 'lastModifier' in x, list(revision)));
```